# Sharing the same DataServiceContext across multiple method calls - good or bad?

Tags: c#, wcf, dataservice

I am wondering what is the standard practice for how DataServiceContext instances should be used. If I have a class that has multiple methods in it that need to perform operations on the context should I create a new instance of the context inside each method, or have the context be a single member of the class which is shared by all the methods?

I am asking this because I recently saw a comment made by another developer in some code I am working on that mentioned the need to recreate the context after adding some objects and  before performing some more operations on it.

i.e. Should I be doing this:

```
public class ServiceHelper
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    DataContext ctx = new DataContext(Uri);

    //do something with the context and call SaveChanges()
  }

  public int GetSometing()
  {
    DataContext ctx = new DataContext(Uri);

    return ctx.GetSomething();
   }
}
```

or this:

```
public class ServiceHelper
{
  private readonly DataContext _ctx = new DataContext(Uri);

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    //do something with _ctx and call SaveChanges()
  }

  public int GetSomething()
  {
    return _ctx.GetSomething();
  }
}
```

?

Also I should add that this is in the context of an ASP.NET MVC application so the ServiceHelper class here is going to be reconstructed on each page request.

**EDIT**

Ok so it seems like either would technically valid according to Msft, as these are short  lived classes, but I am still wondering if both are equally "safe" and equivalent. i.e. if  I add/update some entities and call SaveChanges, then potentially a separate application  makes an update to the same entities and then I retrieve those entities again using the  same context instance is everything going to behave the same as if I had instead created a  new context before my second operation?

**CONCLUSION**

I just found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I think it helps explain the difference:

> By default, the client only materializes an entry in the response feed
>   into an object for entities that are not already being tracked by the
>   DataServiceContext. This means that changes to objects already in the
>   cache are not overwritten. This behavior is controlled by specifying a
>   MergeOption value for queries and load operations. This option is
>   specified by setting the MergeOption property on the
>   DataServiceContext. The default merge option value is AppendOnly. This
>   only materializes objects for entities that are not already being
>   tracked, which means that existing objects are not overwritten.
>   Another way to prevent changes to objects on the client from being
>   overwritten by updates from the data service is to specify
>   PreserveChanges. When you specify OverwriteChanges, values of objects
>   on the client are replaced by the latest values from the entries in
>   the response feed, even if changes have already been made to these
>   objects.

So it looks like if I update some entities and then a separate application makes further changes and then I retrieve those entities again using the same DataServiceContext instance then it depends on what the `MergeOption` is set to whether I will get the entities in the state that they are in the database or just in the state that I last had them locally.

Comment: This class seams like an over engineered global. Is such a thing really a good idea? There should be a better ways of passing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Msdn [says it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx)

> In general, a DataContext instance is designed to last for one "unit
>   of work" however your application defines that term. A DataContext is
>   lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical LINQ to SQL
>   application creates DataContext instances at method scope or as a
>   member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of related
>   database operations.

Providing of course you use LINQ to SQL. But even in other technologies/libraries context is *usually* a very lightweight object. In most cases physical connection is not torn down (but a logical is). I'd guess your concern is to do with connection pooling, so as long as you use one (which you should) then just follow msdn recommendation.  So

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using(DataContext ctx = new DataContext(Uri))
    {
         //do something with the context and call SaveChanges()
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess either would be valid then as I would consider these classes to be "short lived". Seems like recreating in every method is maybe safer, but member of class is cleaner/less code.

Comment: It's up to your application really. The idea is the `*context` is lightweight, just don't keep it lingering for long time.

Comment: I would really like to know, why shouldn't I just keep it around? What behaviour is different when adding/updating/retrieving entities from a freshly instantiated context vs. a context I've already used to perform some other operations (ignoring performance differences)?

Comment: Also: the class that owns the DataContext instance(s) doesn't manage its lifecycle. Someone might build a desktop version of the app that uses this data context manager _without_ any adherence to the norms of stateless app design.

Comment: Because context is associated with a *unit of work*. It is more or less a transaction. You wouldn't keep a transaction open for long time would you? In a context, that would mean to keep all the changes in memory, because you may want to revert something (by design). If you keep it open for long time, you occupy memory with stuff that is not needed, hence you have less memory to process other request. At least this is my understanding.